# Is there something like batch file in Ubuntu?

Tags: 14.04, batch

I have Ubuntu 14.04 installed. I was using Windows until my Windows 7 corrupted.
I was learning about batch file (.bat or .cmd).
Is there anything alike with it in Ubuntu?
If there is what is it?

Comment: .sh files are what you are looking for

Comment: [http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO.html)

Comment: The question should be whether Windows has something remotely as good as Linux/Unix scripting language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is. It goes by many names. It is shell-scripts. BASH,Shell,BOURNE scripts, etc. In Linux, these scripts are in .sh format.

There are plenty of resources on learning more about shell scripting, hence google, Ask Ubuntu., even Youtube. There are books you can read as well on it. I recommend getting Classic Shell Scripting by O'Rielly. It is a great beginners book.